# Running Ubuntu On My OCZ RevoDrive 2 - No such drivers exist?

Tags: drivers, ssd, patch

Would anyone know if there are future plans or a possiblity of getting some drivers for my SSD; There is very little to no support from OCZ regarding linux drivers - Is there a coder out there that could write up a patch or something? Is that possible?

Cheers Guys,

Coryn

Answer (score 2):

The RevoDrives rely on so called "FakeRAID" to run. They work just fine but require you to install `dmraid` package before Ubuntu can use it.

To install upon it, this basically requires you to:

- Run "Try Ubuntu" first. You can't skip straight to installation.
- Open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get install dmraid`.
- Then run the installer. It should detect the new disk for what it is.

Comment: Raid is for multiple drives, not a single drive, so has nothing to do with this.  In particular, `dmraid` is just a tool for configuring software raid to access multiple drives otherwise configured for use in a fake hardware raid system.

Comment: @psusi A Revodrive consists of multiple drives and a fakeraid controller, all on a PCI-E card. I know this because I have one and that's why I suggest `dmraid`.

Comment: I could have sworn that the RevoDrive did NOT pretend to be an AHCI controller with one, let alone multiple SATA drives attached, and thus, requires a proprietary driver to access.  If the individual drives do show up, and you want to raid them, then you are better off using traditional Linux mdadm raid instead of dmraid, as it is more reliable and better supported.  Of course, if you dual boot with windows, then you need to use dmraid since Windows does not recognize Linux raid.

Comment: @psusi The Revodrive 3 requires a proprietary RAID driver (no Ubuntu support AFAIK). The first two lines are open Silicon Image RAID controllers with multiple disks. I did consider `mdadm` but had already set up `dmraid` and was getting the full speed so never changed. I would be interested to see a benchmark though.

Answer (score 1):

the above solution applies only for old ubuntu versions where dmraid was not a part of the OS and it helps only installation of the OS but you still cannot boot from the Revodrive itself (not boot sector on the ssd) but only if you let Ubuntu to install the bootloader onto one of your alternative Sata drives, hdds....